# Why does this javascript example leak memory?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, es6-promise

I am confused why this code example has a memory leak.

```js
// ephemeralLeak.js

async function promiseValue(value) {
  return value;
}

async function run() {
  for (;;) {
    await Promise.race([promiseValue("foo"), promiseValue("bar")]);
  }
}

run();
```

I am running it in Node 20.10.0 like...

```
node --max-old-space-size=512 test/examples/ephemeralLeak.js
```

The result is...

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[13958:0x6859c60]     5576 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 509.6 (519.9) -> 508.8 (519.9) MB, 15.20 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.285, current mu = 0.278) allocation failure; 
[13958:0x6859c60]     5630 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 509.8 (520.2) -> 509.0 (520.4) MB, 10.20 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.285, current mu = 0.278) allocation failure; 
[13958:0x6859c60]     5684 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 510.1 (520.4) -> 509.4 (520.7) MB, 4.11 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.285, current mu = 0.278) allocation failure; 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xc9e850 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xb720ff  [node]
 3: 0xec1a70 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 4: 0xec1d57 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 5: 0x10d3dc5  [node]
 6: 0x10d4354 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
 7: 0x10eb244 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, char const*) [node]
 8: 0x10eba5c v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0x10edbba v8::internal::Heap::HandleGCRequest() [node]
10: 0x1058fd7 v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts() [node]
11: 0x14fa98a v8::internal::Runtime_StackGuard(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
12: 0x1934ef6  [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I was trying to write it up as an example that DIDN'T have a memory leak while illustrating some more problematic code. However, it has a memory leak too and I can't see why.

I know `Promise.race()` calls `then` on each promise. For that reason if you keep racing the same promise there are an increasing number of  `then` subscribers on a promise you still have a reference to. This can't be garbage collected and leads to a memory leak.

See this known Javascript bug/feature for the kind of problem you get with a long-lived promise... https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/17469

However in the above code, all promises are ephemeral. They only last for a single iteration of the loop and should be able to be garbage collected as no references are kept.

Nevertheless I always end up with `JavaScript heap out of memory`

As an interesting contrasting case, this alternative implementation doesn't create a memory leak. Update: I have now drafted this as an answer, but not selected it as I think others might have better knowledge.

```js
// setImmediateNoLeak.js

function promiseValue(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setImmediate(() => resolve(value));
  });
}

async function run() {
  for (;;) {
    await Promise.race([promiseValue("foo"), promiseValue("bar")]);
  }
}

run();
```

Although the above seems to be a workaround, can anyone see why the original ephemeralLeak.js leads to a memory leak or propose a better approach to fix it?

Comment: *They only last for a single iteration of the loop* — why do you think this is true? It clearly is not.

Comment: "eligible for garbage collection" and "being garbage collected" are different things. GC may very well try to avoid running too often.

Comment: Also the fact that each Promise instance will resolve kind-of implies that they have to stick around.

Comment: @VLAZ In my experimentation I also added an explicit garbage collection step, and the procedure still arrived at an out-of-memory state, although it took longer to hit it because of the slowdown of explicitly GCing regularly. See gist at https://gist.github.com/cefn/737c101e2130468245b0fce389c95f11

Comment: @Pointy I am not sure I agree with "It clearly is not". It is not clear to me why or how these promises last more than a single iteration, which is the reason for my question. After the race is awaited, there is, for example, no named variable that points to the promise created by the `await Promise.race` statement. If it is clear to you maybe you could explain.

Comment: @Pointy As an alternative, if there's a clear mechanism by which I'm retaining a reference to the promise perhaps you could propose some way in which the Promise.race() can be awaited indefinitely-many times WITHOUT there being a reference to it, presumably triggering this garbage-collection issue? As per the original question I was hoping for either an explanation or a fix. I'd be surprised if every node service having a process doing repeated races always led to a server outage.

Comment: The runtime has to keep track of the Promise instances because it expects they will eventually resolve.

Comment: Thanks, @Pointy but all the Promises have already resolved (thanks to the await). I think maybe the implementation of await is not very smart, meaning that e.g. `for(;;){ await doIt(); }` is effectively composed as `doIt().then(() => doIt()).then(()=>doIt()).then(()=>doIt()).then(()=>doIt())` which I really hoped wasn't the case and makes me fear for the stability of any node server, honestly, assuming people start using top-level await.

Comment: No, `await` does not wait for a Promise to resolve; that is not how the mechanism works.

Comment: `await` does not chain `then` calls as you propose. `await` makes the `async` function *return* and only when the call stack is empty the microtask (due to the resolved promise) will restore the execution context of the `async` function so it resumes beyond the `await` expression: at that point there is only that execution context on the call stack and no pending promise other than the one returned by `run()`. There is no leeway here: it is mandatory by the ECMAScript standard. NB: I could not reproduce your problem: I killed the process after waiting for some time without seeing any errors.

Comment: Thanks for your description @trincot. Could you try with `node --max-old-space-size=8 test/examples/ephemeralLeak.js`. That dies almost immediately for me, while `node --max-old-space-size=8 test/examples/setImmediateNoLeak.js` seems to run indefinitely (that's the contrasting example at the bottom of the original post). Your description is how I understood the situation, which is why the memory leak makes no sense. I was just speculating I'd found a special case that amounts to chaining when the values resolve synchronously (so maybe it never gets back to the event loop).

Comment: Can you try to replace `promiseValue` by `Promise.resolve()` calls? I don't think the `async function promiseValue` has anything to do with this, it just creates an immediately-fulfilled promise

Comment: My suspicion is that somehow `await` and `Promise.race` are special-cased on already-fulfilled promises so that the microtask queue keeps growing from all the promise handlers on the `"bar"` promises. Can you try [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/49480#issuecomment-1704678297)?

Comment: Thanks, Bergi. I had to cap the number at 100000 and exit cleanly to get a trace - hitting the OOM state prevents the trace from happening. The two scenarios (one which resolves synchronously and one which uses setInterval) are very different in the tracing view. The synchronous case has a single, very long pink block labelled 'Run Microtasks (Didn't Finish)' while the setInterval case has a series of stacked and apparently terminating 'Run Microtasks' blocks.

Comment: @Bergi yes I had tried various things with resolve calls, like calling `await Promise.resolve()` before returning from promiseValue. Even when I implemented promiseValue like  `function promiseValue(value) { return Promise.resolve(value); }` it still gets OOM killed. It's super-easy to replicate this issue I believe if you want to see it failing yourself (although if you have a lot of memory you might need to limit it with e.g. `node --max-old-space-size=16` so that it dies promptly.

Comment: @cefn "*a single, very long pink block labelled 'Run Microtasks (Didn't Finish)'*" - that's pretty much expected, you have an infinite loop in the code that keeps queuing microtasks so the microtask checkpoint never completes. However that should not affect GC - unless the queue is growing faster than it can be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Wild speculation, could Promise.race wire up functions that resolve immediately to sync values in a different way to the ones which are promises with an actual callback that returns to the event loop.

Maybe for these synchronously resolved values it never returns to the event loop, thinking it can settle everything synchronously so it never terminates and the next task in the event loop never runs which would tidy up some kind of accumulated state (thanks @Bergi).

If that's the case one way to work around this is to ensure that even immediately-available values are resolved only after a visit to the event loop.

Below I changed the promiseValue call so that it never resolves synchronously. And indeed the below code doesn't have a memory leak!

This has the effect of the original task loop, but without the memory leaks and runtime failures because the underlying implementation doesn't keep accumulating some kind of partial state without a chance to clear it up.

```js
// setImmediateNoLeak.js

function promiseValue(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setImmediate(() => resolve(value));
  });
}

async function run() {
  for (;;) {
    await Promise.race([promiseValue("foo"), promiseValue("bar")]);
  }
}

run();
```

Comment: I think you fundamentally do not understand how `async` and `await` work in JavaScript.

Comment: An `async` function is like a generator function. The `await` expressions inside the function yield a Promise value, which when resolved resumes the function at the yield point (the `await`). The runtime has to keep track of the pending promises.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, with that clarity, I'd really value your answers to the two questions I raised in the original post. Question 1: Why are any promises pending and/or referenced after an await line has completed? The race has fulfilled, both its 'child' promises have fulfilled. No scoped reference to them is retained. Question 2: Is there a correct way using async/await to repeatedly run a race, or do we just need to be careful to always have orchestration code that DOESN'T use async/await because of what I consider to be a bug, but I think you consider a feature.

Comment: ...and by the way one fundamental of a generator function is that it DOESN'T retain every yielded result, else you couldn't have an infinite generator, which is why this seems so problematic for async/await.

Comment: Also given that this loop without Promise.race doesn't create a memory leak, I strongly doubt it has anything to do with the fundamentals of loops and async/await.. Seems to be a bug related to Promise.race `async function promiseValue(value) {
  return value;
}

async function run() {
  for (;;) {
    await promiseValue("foo");
    await promiseValue("bar");
  }
}

run();
`

Comment: Working around the problem with `setImmediate` does not really answer the question in my opinion, as you now have different tasks running in succession, while the original script only had one infinitely-running task. *"because promises don't end up infinitely chained onto each other"*: there is no evidence of this in your question. All we see is that the garbage collector runs itself into a heap limit, but there is no evidence of what is filling up memory.

Comment: @trincot agreed that trick was the wrong way to use setImmediate. I updated the answer to use strategy which also works, but that now has one indefinitely-running task. With the modified use of setImmediate the values themselves simply never resolve without returning to the event loop.

Comment: @Pointy "*The runtime has to keep track of the pending promises.*" - no, it only has to keep track of async things that might resolve a promise. And it has to keep track of reactions to settled promises that didn't run yet (i.e. the microtask queue). But there is no special GC handling of (pending) promise objects themselves.

Comment: In spite of unhelpful commenters claiming I "don't understand async and await in javascript", this flawed behaviour has now been identified as a `confirmed-bug` in the NodeJS Promise.race and Promise.any implementation... https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/51452